# Cartthrob 2 / Moneris Payment Gateway

Tags: cartthrob

Is there a difference in US based Moneris accounts and CA based Moneris accounts in terms of API integration / payment gateway plugin usage.

Client has a US-based account, but my developer cannot get it to work with the current plugin (which, according to Moneris, appear to be trying to access the CA-based API).

Any thoughts?

Sam

Comment: Turns out the Moneris US dev environment was broken. That is why we couldn't get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two API's for Moneris: one for the Canada payment gateway and one for the USA payment gateway.

#1. To use the USA gateway you will need to first download the Moneris USA API.

> Both the USA API and Canada API can be downloaded from http://developer.moneris.com (free registration required)

#2. Once you have the USA API you then need to make some minor changes to your code so that it works with the USA API. Refer to the sample code that comes with the USA API in order to identify the exact changes that you need to make.

> Here's an example change that you need to make if you do purchase transactions: change the transaction type from purchase to us_purchase.